# Quicksilver accessible script for disabling and enabling Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, quicksilver

I'd like to disable and enable Time Machine at will via Quicksilver.

'nuff said.

Do you're thang, nerds. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just realized I could copy it out of another script I use to detect displays.

Here they are:

Disable:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
                click menu item "Time Machine" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
                tell button "OFF" of window 1 to click
        end tell
    end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Enable:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
                click menu item "Time Machine" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
                tell button "ON" of window 1 to click
        end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Hope that helps someone else. If there's a better solution, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this AppleScript to start a Time Machine backup:

```
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd-helper &"
```

or use a similar shell script.

I think Time Machine runs *way* too often.  Instead, I leave Time Machine disabled and use [Awaken](http://embraceware.com/awaken/) to run this script twice daily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [TimeMachineEditor](http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/) for modifying the schedule